# How to identify that the Word document is modified and saved in Office JS Add-in?

Tags: ms-word, office-js

I am currently developing a JavaScript-based Office Add-in for Microsoft Word, and I need to dynamically edit the footer whenever the document is modified and saved. I'm wondering if there's a way to detect these events in Office JS. Specifically:

**Save Event Handling:**
Can I set up an event handler for document save, so that I can perform actions like editing the footer when the user saves the document?

**Close Event Handling:**
Can I set up an event handler for document close, so that I can perform an action before the user closes the document?

I digged in the documentation and could find only this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.document?view=word-js-preview#word-word-document-saved-member: Which indicates whether the changes in the document have been saved.
But I couldn't find any way to hook the save event

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the feature: save/close event, you requested, is not a part of the product. We track Office Add-in feature requests on our [Microsoft 365 Developer Platform Ideas Forum](https://aka.ms/m365dev-suggestions). Please add your request there. Feature requests on are considered when we go through our planning process. Thanks, Microsoft 365 Developer Platform team ​